# Does the Commerce API allow you to receive a query (via Webhooks or REST) that lets you know when a payment has been detected?

Tags: coinbase-api

I'm rebuilding the CoinbaseCommerceButton component from scratch, and in order to improve the end-user experience I want to allow the user to continue on using my app after a payment has been detected. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are currently two ways to do this.

### 1. CoinbaseCommerceButton

There is an `onPaymentDetected` callback as documented [here](https://github.com/coinbase/react-coinbase-commerce#props). After the callback is triggered, you can safely remove the button from the DOM and allow the user to continue using your application.

### 2. Webhook Subscriptions

Detected payments can also be registered for via webhooks with the `charge:pending` event type. See [here](https://commerce.coinbase.com/docs/api/#webhooks) for a more detailed explanation of how this can be achieved.